# python printing from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to write code that will collect the number of individuals attending an event. Based on the number of people entered, I will ask that many times a) the name of the individual, b) the number of toys they have donated.  I want the information to be entered into a dictionary which i will pass to another function.  The second function will select individuals who have donated more than 20 toys and print their name and the number of toys the donated as "level 1" and then everyone else as "level 2".

I've checked to make sure that the data is being passed from one function to another correctly.  I'm having issues printing the donation amount without the [].  Also, it keeps printing the level above each entry instead of listing the entries underneath the level. In other words, I'm trying to get:

> Level 1
>   Selena Gomez 50
>   Beyonce 40
>
> Level 2
>   Will Smith 5

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
def data():
    people = int(input("How many individuals are attending? "))
    attendees = {}
    for i in range(people):
        name = str(input('Please enter name: '))
        amount = int(input('Number of toys donated:'))
        attendees[name]= [amount]

    return attendees




def print_data():
    attendees = data()

    for i in attendees:
        if attendees[i][0] > 20:
            print('Level 1')
            print(i, attendees[i])

        else:    
            print('Level 2')
            print(i, attendees[i])

print_data()
```

And here is my output:

> How many individuals are attending? 3
>
> Please enter name: Will Smith
>
> Number of toys donated:5
>
> Please enter name: Selena Gomez
>
> Number of toys donated:50
>
> Please enter name: Beyonce
>
> Number of toys donated:40
>
> Level 2
>   Will Smith [5]
>
> Level 1
>   Selena Gomez [50]
>
> Level 1
>   Beyonce [40]

Comment: Just remove the brackets here: `attendees[name]=[amount]` should be `attendees[name]= amount` otherwise you are saving a list to the dictionary. That's why it displays the brackets in the output.

Comment: Why are you adding the brackets in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did two mistakes, you were taking input as list as value of each dictionary element and you have to run two different loops to find the all the values greater than 20 and another one to print all the values less than 20

```
def data():
    people = int(input("How many individuals are attending? "))
    attendees1 = {}
    attendees2 = {}
    for i in range(people):
        name = str(input('Please enter name: '))
        amount = int(input('Number of toys donated:'))
        #amount should be just a variable not list
        if amount > 20:
            attendees1[name]= amount
        else:
            attendees2[name] = amount

    return attendees1, attendees2




def print_data():
    attendees1, attendees2 = data()


    if len(attendees1) > 0:
        print('Level 1')
        for i in attendees1:
            print(i, attendees1[i])

    if len(attendees2) > 0:
        print('Level 2')
        for i in attendees2:
            print(i, attendees2[i])

print_data()
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest how I get the level number to appear only once with the appropriate items below it? it's still printing the level above EACH item.

Comment: sorry my bad, updated the code, now see it, just printing the level1,2 one time outside the loop

Comment: Thank you -perfect.  Now I just need to figure out how to get those levels not to print if there are no items that fall into those categories.

Comment: updated once again :D, if it solves your problem, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

These two lines should be edited:

```
attendees[name]= [amount]
#into
attendees[name]= amount
#and
if attendees[i][0] > 20:
#into
if attendees[i] > 20:
```

Comment: Thank you, zipa.  This addresses the [] issue, but any thoughts on how I get the level number to appear only once with the appropriate items below it?  it's still printing the level above EACH item.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work for you?

```
def data():
    people = int(input("How many individuals are attending? "))
    attendees = {}
    for i in range(people):
        name = str(input('Please enter name: '))
        amount = int(input('Number of toys donated:'))
        attendees[name]= amount
    return attendees


def print_data(attendees):
    level_one = []
    level_two = []
    for name, count in attendees.items():
        if count >= 20:
            level_one.append((name, count))
        else:
            level_two.append((name, count))

    print('Level 1')
    for name, count in level_one:
        print(name, count)

    print('\nlevel 2')
    for name, count in level_two:
        print(name, count)


attendees = data()
print_data(attendees)
```